# print_int and other F# print functions

Tags: f#

I am trying to do simple tutorial in Visual Studio
let someNumber = (2 + 2)
print_int someNumber
but it says print_int is undefined. printfn works. 
Could the book I'm using be outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

print_int is a part of the F# power pack.  Adding a reference to the PowerPack (c:\program files\FSharp-1.9.6.2\bin\FSharp.PowerPack.dll on my machine) should fix the issue.

Here is a blog entry from Don that mentions the current plans for the Power Pack:

http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2008/12/10/fsharp-to-ship-as-part-of-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually, print_int is not in FSharp.PowerPack.dll, at least not in the latest version (PowerPack version 1.9.9.9).  It's in FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility.dll.

FYI, to use print_int, print_endline, etc. in the F# Interactive window (and turn off the warnings about ML compatibility) use the following commands:

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility.dll";;
#nowarn "62";;
```